# Should I send a "goodbye" email to client's employees who I worked with?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, clients

I am employed by a consulting company (let's call them Initech), and have been deputed to work for a client (call them Acme). I have been working out of Acme's office, almost since the time Initech hired me. I am the only Initech employee working for Acme (other Initech employees work for other companies).

I have now resigned from Initech, and would be leaving them in about a week's time. At my previous jobs, I have sent a "goodbye" mail to my colleagues on the last day as a custom/etiquette (which I believe is quite prevalent anyway).

This is, however, my first job as a consultant, and I am in a predicament. It doesn't *feel* right to "just pack your stuff and leave" without sending the goodbye email. There isn't anyone at Initech whom I could send this mail to, since the only people with whom I have had *some* interaction are my manager (whom I am going to thank separately anyway), and 3 guys who interviewed me (all of whom have already left Initech).

All my work relationships on this job have been with Acme's employees. However, I am not sure if sending such emails to a client's employees is considered good etiquette. I don't want to bother my Initech manager with this question, he certainly wouldn't bother either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in my experience it is normal practice for consultants to send "goodbye" emails to the clients they have been working with. As well as being courteous by letting them know you are leaving and wishing them well, it is also a good networking opportunity to inform/remind them of your contact details.

Whether you are moving to another consulting firm or a permanent position, it's always useful to allow colleagues to keep in touch.

Comment: This is also the norm when a project is finished in the usual way.

Answer (score 5):

Ask your manager i.e. the manager in the company that cuts your checks if it's OK to send a farewell note to the client's personnel and management. I personally see nothing wrong and harmful with you doing it but your own management may want to deal with the issue of communicating to the client that you are departing themselves, in their own style and with the timing of their own choosing. What if, for example, you had announced to the client that you are departing, and the client immediately calls your management to ask what happens next when your management is still struggling to decide as to whom to substitute for you?

I'd say, send your farewell note but coordinate with your own management first to make sure that they have their ducks lined up.

Answer (score 4):

It should not be a problem to send an e-mail to your colleagues to let them know that you are moving on.  I have seen this done and no one has questioned it.